# Writing Javascript Variable into <a href> - without onclick

Tags: javascript, gps

This is most recent

Anyone know why this wont redirect?

```
 function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("location").href = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude;

var redirectUrl = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude; 

}

function redirect() 
{ 
    window.location.href = redirectUrl; 
} 
setTimeout(redirect,15000);
```

I'm stuck on brain fart mode and can't seem to write a javascript variable to an A anchor href.  Ideas? I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

So Javascript is pulling GPS below - works fine...

I need it to populate the Lat and Long into an anchor href... Without an "onclick" - needs to populate automatically...

So:

```
 <a href="page.htm?Lat=javascript(latitude)&Long=javascript(longitude)">GPS Location</a>

 javascript(latitude) - is variable I need to pull from below Javascript
 javascript(longitude) - is variable I need to pull from below Javascript

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   function getLocationConstant()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError);   
    } else {
        alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
    }
}

// If we have a successful location update
function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;

}

// If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
function onGeoError(event)
{
    alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
}

   </script>
```

Comment: Got it figured by removing var before redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="" id="location">GPS Location</a>

<script>
function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;

    document.getElementById("location").href = "page.htm?Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Comment: seems to not load the correct url - only loads to page.htm - no question mark or coordinates after...

Comment: Does it populate the placeholders on the page with the correct values?

Comment: Ends a href quotes properly yes... And shows link GPS Location properly... No coordinate data - I can get the onclick to pull into a form with other coding fine...

Comment: The code should work - http://jsfiddle.net/4SRzH/ Check your page for duplicate `id`-s (maybe you have already an element with `#location`) or other errors

Comment: See below - I voted u up one as it got me started. Needed the onload in body to pull though, now have redirect problem

Answer (score 0):

Zoltan got me started in right direction - couldn't get it too pull, had to add an onload in body.

Now I'm trying to redirect to that url and it wont go with javascript redirect...

Thx Zoltan

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

// Get a single location update
function getLocationConstant()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError,{enableHighAccuracy:true,maximumAge:0});
    } else {
        alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
    }
}

// If we have a successful location update
function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("location").href = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude;

var redirectUrl = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude; 

}

// If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
function onGeoError(event)
{
    alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
}

function redirect() 
{ 
    window.location = redirectUrl; 
} 
setTimeout(redirect,15000); 
  </script>


  </head>

  <body onload="getLocationConstant()">
   <br><br>
  <a href="" id="location">URL?</a>
```